SES verified identity: domain vs email conflict
If a domain identity is successfully verified, I understand that I can send from ANY email address in that domain. But what if there is also an email identity under the same domain that failed verification? Can I still send an email with that address?
Success: "example.com" (domain)
Failed: "email@example.com" (email)

Another example, what if example.com is verified and email@example.com is Pending verification?
Update: I answered the question on pending. I was able to send an email in this state. Now I'll wait 24 hours (when verification fails) to confirm the original question.

Yes, if the domain is verified, even if the email address's verification is pending or failed, you can send an email from it.
The docs were unclear, so I answered this question empirically. I set up a verified domain and an email address with failed verification.
